# Combining multiple fields of Pair RDD in single pass

Tags: apache-spark

Suppose I define the following RDD:

```
baseRDD= sc.parallelize( [(0,{'id':1, 'fld1':2.0, 'fld2':3.0}),
                          (0,{'id':2, 'fld1':4.0, 'fld2':5.0}),
                          (1,{'id':1, 'fld1':6.0, 'fld2':10.0}),
                          (1,{'id':2, 'fld1':10.0, 'fld2':15.0}),
                          (1,{'id':3, 'fld1':20.0, 'fld2':25.0})])
```

I would to combine the corr. fields above by key so as to produce this rdd:

```
[(0,6.0,8.0),(1,36.0,50.0)]
```

I know I can do it on a field by field basis as follows:

```
fld1RDD = baseRDD.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1]['fld1'])).\
          reduceByKey(lambda x,y: (x+y))
fld2RDD = baseRDD.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1]['fld2'])).\
          reduceByKey(lambda x,y: (x+y))
```

and then

```
  fld1RDD.join(fld2RDD).collect()
```

to produce

```
  [(0, (6.0, 8.0)), (1, (36.0, 50.0))]
```

but is there a more efficient way of doing this so the code doesn't have to
make multiple passes over baseRDD ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always convert your data to a structure which can be aggregated directly for example `Counter`:

```py
from collections import Counter
from operator import add

baseRDD.combineByKey(Counter, add, add).collect()
## [(0, Counter({'fld1': 6.0, 'fld2': 8.0, 'id': 3})),
##  (1, Counter({'fld1': 36.0, 'fld2': 50.0, 'id': 6}))]
```

or `NumPy` array:

```py
from operator import itemgetter
import numpy as np

(baseRDD.combineByKey(
    lambda x: np.array(itemgetter("fld1", "fld2")(x)), add, add
).collect()
## [(0, array([ 6.,  8.])), (1, array([ 36.,  50.]))]
```